# Tensorflow: How can I add loss based on layer's weights?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I know I can add a value to loss with "add_loss()" in custom layers, but I'm wondering how to do this with layer weights. I'd like to consider layer weights as the loss value.

What I want to do is like this below. What I'm doing is considering layer weights as regularization when learning the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(MyDense, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w), self.w  # return layer's weights as well


class AddLossLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddLossLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, weights):
        # add a value to loss based on the weights (F() is a function to calculate the value.)
        self.add_loss(F(weights))
        return inputs


inputs = tf.keras.Input((4,))
x, weights = MyDense(1)(inputs)
outputs = AddLossLayer()(x, weights)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Even though I tried to convert weights to ndarray with .numpy() in the AddLossLayer, it didn't work. In some cases, I might be able to just use tensorflow regularization, but I need to do something more versatile.

I appreciate your help in advance!